# Extracting MM-YYYY from python date and creating a new column with the same

Tags: python

I want to extract the month and year from one of my date columns in the dataset and create a new column in the data-frame with the new MM-YYY format.

My current solution is working fine but its way to long. I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

Date point looks like this: 2017-07-26 and its in datetime64[ns] format and I want the output to look like this: Jul-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
df1['Month'] = df1['booking_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, "%B-%Y"))
```